# Unable to install mock package on MacOSX using pip

Tags: python, mocking, pip

Getting the following error when I do > pip install mock in a virtualenv

```
(test)mystogans-mac:clean_arch resnet$ pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall mock
Downloading/unpacking mock
  Downloading mock-1.1.3.tar.gz (70kB): 70kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mock
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/Users/resnet/Documents/workspace/CodePython/clean_arch/test/build/mock/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        setuptools_installed = StrictVersion(setuptools.version.__version__)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/Users/resnet/Documents/workspace/CodePython/clean_arch/test/build/mock/setup.py", line 10, in <module>

setuptools_installed = StrictVersion(setuptools.version.__version__)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same problem with this on travis: https://travis-ci.org/bouncestorage/swiftproxy/builds/70313913 . I fixed it by upgrading pip and setuptools:

```
$ ./virtualenv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
$ ./virtualenv/bin/pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
```

I use virtualenv but the same should work for you without.